# Split a java string among < > brackets, including the brackets, but only if no space between brackets

Tags: java, regex, split

I need to be able to turn a string, for instance `"This and <those> are."`, into a string array of the form `["This and ", "<those>", " are."]`. I have been trying to using the String.split() command, and I've gotten this regex:

`"(?=[<>])"`

However, this just gets me `["This and ", "<those", "> are."]`. I can't figure out a good regex to get the brackets all on the same element, and I also can't have spaces between those brackets. So for instance, `"This and <hey there> are."` Should be simply split to `["This and <hey there> are."]`. Ideally I'd like to just rely solely on the split command for this operation. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Why does `"This and <hey there> are."` not split to `["This", "and", "<hey there>", "are."]`?

Comment: @Bohemian Because ProfessorCool specifically said: "I also can't have spaces between those brackets".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not actually possible; given that the 'separator' needs to match 0 characters it needs to be all lookahead/lookbehind, and those require fixed-size lookups; you need to look ahead arbitrarily far into the string to know if a space is going to occur or not, thus, what you want? Impossible.

Just write a regexp that *FINDS* the construct you want, that's a lot simpler. Simply `Pattern.compile("<\\w+>")` (taking a select few liberties on what you intend a thing-in-brackets to look like. If truly it can be ANYTHING except spaces and the closing brace, `"<[^ >]+>"` is what you want).

Then, just loop through, finding as you go:

```java
private static final Pattern TOKEN_FINDER = Pattern.compile("<\\w+>");

List<String> parse(String in) {
  Matcher m = TOKEN_FINDER.matcher(in);
  if (!m.find()) return List.of(in);

  var out = new ArrayList<String>();
  int pos = 0;
  do {
    int s = m.start();
    if (s > pos) out.add(in.substring(pos, s));
    out.add(m.group());
    pos = m.end();
  } while (m.find());
  if (pos < in.length()) out.add(in.substring(pos));
  return out;
}
```

Let's try it:

```
System.out.println(parse("This and <those> are."));
System.out.println(parse("This and <hey there> are."));
System.out.println(parse("<edgecase>2"));
System.out.println(parse("3<edgecase>"));
```

prints:

```
[This and , <those>,  are.]
[This and <hey there> are.]
[<edgecase>]
[<edgecase>, 2]
[3, <edgecase>]
```

seems like what you wanted.